# docker run --net = "host" equivalent in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to run my dokcer image in `docker-compose` with `--net = "host"` as my docker run with `--net = "host"` works fine.

But I wanna do it with docker-compose. I also added `network_mode: "host"` to my `docker-compose.yml` file. But no chance. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  campaign-app-avano-mci:
    image: imagename
    ports:
      - "4558:4558"
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - /apps/dockers/campaign-app-avano-mci/:/logs
    environment:
      - SDP_MONGO_DATABASE="campaign-app-avano-mci"
      - SDP_SDK_PORT="4558"
      - SDP_PLATFORM_URL="host-platform:9600/aban-platform"
```

any suggestion?

Comment: What is the issue you face? Because you have used it correctly

Comment: Tried without the "ports" parameters ? In host mode it is useless

Comment: I want my container get an IP from docker network and expose mentioned port to main machine. but out hosted application in docker container get time out and make it exit after 1 minutes!

Comment: To publish a port from a container to the host machine, you don't need `network_mode: "host"`. I'm wondering what `host-platform` is and how you want to access it. Probably there are some dns resolution problems. Can you find anything in the logs (`docker-compose logs campaign-app-avano-mci`)?

Comment: problem resolved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem resolved with following docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
  campaign-app-avano-mci:
    image: imagefile
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
    - 4558:4558
    volumes:
      - /apps/dockers/campaign-app-avano-mci/:/logs
    environment:
      - SDP_MONGO_DATABASE=campaign-app-avano-mci
      - SDP_SDK_PORT=4558
      - SDP_PLATFORM_URL=host-platform:9600/aban-platform
```